# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jax.experimental.vectorize'

Tags: python, module, vectorization, modulenotfounderror, jax

I had this issue when I was working on a code that was not mine, and I was really overwhelmed by it for a month without a fixed any help online.

I have jax-0.4.10 installed and Using a Mac book Pro.

I never found any solution online probably because this error was specifically my problem.

Comment: A common reason is that the package was installed for another `--version` of Python as the one you use to execute the code.

Comment: It's strange cause the Python version installed on my PC is 3.10.10 which is the same as the one I found in the requirements of the repository's code.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I didn't have ** jaxrk ** installed, so I did the following commands to automatically install all requirements/dependecies and packages that the repo was using:

> `pip install git+https://github.com/[ORGANIZATION NAME]/JaxRk`

> `pip install ".[ci]”`

That worked so well for me